# kendo-ui bind observable to content editable

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a one off situation where I'm not using the kendoGrid to display my data. Instead, I'm displaying my data in a normal HTML table where the rows and columns are static. In this case I've bound my table to viewModel and set the `<td>` elements as `contenteditable`:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
            <th scope="col">Federal</th>
            <th scope="col">State</th>
            <th scope="col">Local</th>
            <th scope="col">NG</th>
            <th scope="col">Other</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Projected</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Full Time</th>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-bind="text: viewModel.FederalFullTime"></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-bind="text: viewModel.StateFullTime"></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-bind="text: viewModel.LocalFullTime"></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-bind="text: viewModel.NonGovernmentFullTime"></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-bind="text: viewModel.OtherFullTime"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: viewModel.TotalFullTime"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Part Time</th>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-bind="text: viewModel.FederalPartTime"></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-bind="text: viewModel.StatePartTime"></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-bind="text: viewModel.LocalPartTime"></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-bind="text: viewModel.NonGovernmentPartTime"></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" data-bind="text: viewModel.OtherPartTime"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: viewModel.TotalPartTime"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Totals</th>
            <td data-bind="text: viewModel.TotalFederal"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: viewModel.TotalState"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: viewModel.TotalLocal"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: viewModel.TotalNonGovernment"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: viewModel.TotalOther"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: viewModel.Total"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Whenever the template that holds the table is initialized, it shows the data in the cells correctly based on their respective bindings. However it does not update the values in the view model if I change the text of the `<td>` using the `contenteditable` feature. I confirmed that the values are not updating by binding the change event of my view model (and it never fires) as well as checking inline via the console:

```
_viewModel.authorizationInterface.viewModel.bind("change", function (e) {
    console.log(e); // Not firing when cell is edited
})
```

Is there a way to force the view model to update when I edit the text of the cell using `contenteditable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [text binding](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/text), which I believe is one-way. The two-way equivalent is [value](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/value), which relies on the DOM [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event), which contenteditable elements do not have.

I think you could do it with a [custom binding](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/custom). In `init`, subscribe to `this.element` [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) and fire the change method there.

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly as you described. If anyone coming to this SO thread, I changed my data-bind from `text` to `contentEditable` and then rigged up the custom binding using the following: https://dojo.telerik.com/idixOKAp